# A package to draw Neural Network kernels logic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, pstricks

So [here are](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) and [here](http://distill.pub/2016/augmented-rnns/) beautiful and simple to understand depictions on NNs. Is there an established package or a common way to draw images like this in TeX (TikZ\PSTricks):
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can ask how the people of the linked example did the drawing. From the looks of it, I would guess that it is "plain" tikz or even something like Microsoft Visio.